# Android record audio output

Tags: android, audio

How is it possible that some apps serve the function to record the
audio output of the android system? Everything I am finding is the
very same tutorial on different sites where you can record MIC input.
I don't care about mic input, I want the audio output and just can't
imagine how to access it. like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.rodrigokolb.realdrum&hl=en)
and [this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=batalsoft.drumsolohd.rock) app

Comment: The linked apps most likely have a number of pre-recorded sounds that are played based off of which "drum" you hit.

Comment: Yes. But how this recorded ? They used soundpool so mixer sound occur, they not marge pre recoded sound.

Comment: The [ToneGenerator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html) might be what you are looking for. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731155/how-to-merge-two-mp3-files-into-one-combine-join) might also be helpful.

Comment: This class provides methods to play DTMF tones (ITU-T Recommendation Q.23), call supervisory tones (3GPP TS 22.001, CEPT) and proprietary tones (3GPP TS 31.111). Depending on call state and routing options, tones are mixed to the downlink audio or output to the speaker phone or headset. This API is not for generating tones over the uplink audio path. but my issue is different

Comment: and the maximum number 32 of simultaneous streams for this SoundPool object so merge mp3 not good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long reaches i found the solution.

1. Bad solution : at first i use [Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#setDataCaptureListener%28android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) this listener provide 8 bit fft and
   waveform frequency , but wav and android audio form at least contain
   16 bit frequency , i save 8 bit frequency and played , this audio
   quality is low and audio contain many noise.
2. Good idea is : Eery game and audio recoded app  that record their audio output , they originally not recorded anything , they
   recoded    which sound is played and they merge recoded file and
   created a    audio file

Answer (score 0):

You can always try getting a set of earphones with a mic, loop the earphone output back into the mic input electrically.  Now whatever you would normally hear on the earphones will get fed back into the mic.  Use a small capacitor to remove any DC bias, maybe 10nF or 0.1uF.  DC bias is present on some devices as a way to allow switch inputs to be used on the earphone jack.

Comment: Ash, there no way to use or add small capacitor in android phone .my app have a one feature it can record that played form the app.

Comment: The small cap does not go into the phone, it goes on the earphone/mic wire.

Answer (score -1):

As your links shows they are about playing music instruments.
If you want to vary your audio based on pressure of the touch, might be Good idea too.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textinfo;
    MotionEvent pressure;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        float press = pressure.getPressure();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        press.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tanks. but my issue is not about playing music instruments .my issue is how to record android audio output