# Mix audio in android

Tags: android

**I tried to follow this link:**

http://mobilengineering.blogspot.com/2012/06/audio-mix-and-record-in-android.html?showComment=1369622288028#c2333829870074273419

But after mixing audio files, file (***mixed.wav***) on sdcard can not be played, I do not know why.
Can you help me?. Thank you very much ..

**This my code:**

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
 public static final int FREQUENCY = 44100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        mixSound();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void mixSound() throws IOException {
    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 44100, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    InputStream in1 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.media_b);
    InputStream in2 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.media_c);

    byte[] arrayMusic1 = null;
    arrayMusic1 = new byte[in1.available()];
    arrayMusic1 = createMusicArray(in1);
    in1.close();

    byte[] arrayMusic2 = null;
    arrayMusic2 = new byte[in2.available()];
    arrayMusic2 = createMusicArray(in2);
    in2.close();


    byte[] output = new byte[arrayMusic1.length];

    audioTrack.play();

    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        float samplef1 = arrayMusic1[i] / 128.0f; 
        float samplef2 = arrayMusic2[i] / 128.0f;
        float mixed    = samplef1 + samplef2;

        // reduce the volume a bit:
        mixed *= 0.8;
        // hard clipping
        if (mixed > 1.0f)  mixed = 1.0f;
        if (mixed < -1.0f) mixed = -1.0f;

        byte outputSample = (byte) (mixed * 128.0f);
        output[i]         = outputSample;   
    }

    audioTrack.write(output, 0, output.length);
    convertByteToFile(output);
}

public static byte[] createMusicArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buff = new byte[10240];
    int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0) {
        baos.write(buff, 0, i);
    }

    return baos.toByteArray(); // be sure to close InputStream in calling function

}

public static void convertByteToFile(byte[] fileBytes) throws FileNotFoundException {

    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/mixed.wav"));
    try {
        bos.write(fileBytes);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're outputting is just the PCM data. A valid WAV file also needs a header:

```
Offset    Size  Name           Description
------------------------------------------------------------------------
0         4     ChunkID        Contains the letters "RIFF" in ASCII form
                               (0x52494646 big-endian form).
4         4     ChunkSize      36 + SubChunk2Size, or more precisely:
                               4 + (8 + SubChunk1Size) + (8 + SubChunk2Size)
                               This is the size of the rest of the chunk 
                               following this number.  This is the size of the 
                               entire file in bytes minus 8 bytes for the
                               two fields not included in this count:
                               ChunkID and ChunkSize.
8         4     Format         Contains the letters "WAVE"
                               (0x57415645 big-endian form).

12        4     Subchunk1ID    Contains the letters "fmt "
                               (0x666d7420 big-endian form).
16        4     Subchunk1Size  16 for PCM.  This is the size of the
                               rest of the Subchunk which follows this number.
20        2     AudioFormat    PCM = 1 (i.e. Linear quantization)
                               Values other than 1 indicate some 
                               form of compression.
22        2     NumChannels    Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc.
24        4     SampleRate     8000, 44100, etc.
28        4     ByteRate       == SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
32        2     BlockAlign     == NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
                               The number of bytes for one sample including
                               all channels. I wonder what happens when
                               this number isn't an integer?
34        2     BitsPerSample  8 bits = 8, 16 bits = 16, etc.
          2     ExtraParamSize if PCM, then doesn't exist
          X     ExtraParams    space for extra parameters

36        4     Subchunk2ID    Contains the letters "data"
                               (0x64617461 big-endian form).
40        4     Subchunk2Size  == NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
                               This is the number of bytes in the data.
                               You can also think of this as the size
                               of the read of the subchunk following this 
                               number.
```

After this you write the PCM data.

([Reference](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/)).

Comment: How to fix it, I do not know how.
Can you help me? Thank you very much :)

Comment: You write all the fields specified in the header. First the string `RIFF`, then a 32-bit value containing `36+size_of_your_audio_data`, then the string `WAVE`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had mixed success. But mixed.wav file with noise. How to fix it, remove white noise. What do I do with my wav byte array. Can you help me?

Comment: You should write the PCM data immediately following the header. You could double-check that your PCM data is ok by dumping it to a file without any header and then importing it as raw PCM data in Audacity on your PC.

Comment: After I switched to short[] it works very bad :( I do not know where I was wrong.

Comment: @Michael : Can you provide me the solution of How did you mix two audio files?? I am not able to achieve this..Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Siddharth_Vyas have you got the solutions for mixing two audio files.Please tell me is it possible and if it is give a way to do it.Any help appreciated..

Comment: @NarenderReddy : Sorry, I was not able to get the solution.