# FFMPEG Android library

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to combine image and audio to form a video file using FFMPEG.
Without using NDK is there any way to create a Android project for FFMPEG.
Please provide any Libraries and Any sample Projects it will helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[ffmpeg-android](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android) work like charm, but weights about 9 mb for app... more ffmpeg options (libs) [HERE](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android)

you may also check [`MediaMuxer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) class (and related) for encoding support with SDK (not NDK), but it needs relatively fresh device (API18 and above). ffmpeg a supports a bit older OS version (API16)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..@snachmsm,.   I found a solution for this FFMPEG, I will post my complete code once done with the sample.

Comment: @Phani varma Any update on the solution you got? Would be really helpful if you could share that how you did it?

Comment: @TheCuriousDev https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android
From the above URL i downloaded code and changed the path as  -y -i /storage/emulated/0/images.jpg -i /storage/emulated/0/rec.wav -acodec aac -vcodec mpeg4 -s 480*320 -f mp4 -r 2 /storage/emulated/0/result.mp4"

Comment: @Phanivarma , how u compiled it ?

Comment: This answer contains a command for merging two sound files https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677342/2294985