# Android Combining audio files

Tags: android, audio

I need to merge several audio files into one, while the Union may be a file on the file.

**Example: the user begins recording a new sound, press to select the desired sounds, while there is a counting of time, in seconds, that is, if the user selects a sound for 6 seconds and 2 seconds choose a sound for 4 seconds the two sounds must lie on top of each other.**

In the end, I will have to remain on the device one sound with any extension (mp3, ogg, wav) to request any information in no not asking for ready-made codes even examples, although literature examples, at least not in time guys.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652432/how-to-mix-overlay-two-mp3-audio-file-into-one-mp3-file-not-concatenate), looks like that won't be easy.

Comment: Are you looking to mix the files (i.e., have the recorded sounds playback simultaneously) or concatenate them (i.e. have one play right after the other)? Either way, there are many answers on SO and many tutorials for both, so can you also explain which ones you looked at and why they were insufficient?

Comment: @Bjorn Roche I need to mix two audio file. Example: write facebook